# Why I get undefined method `meta_keywords' when running rake db:setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, refinerycms

I get this error:
    rake aborted!
    undefined method `meta_keywords' for Page::Translation:0x0000000548d5f0

when running rake db:setup on a refinery cms 1.0.0 rails 3.0.7.

and can't quite debug it

Edit
part of schema:

```
create_table "page_part_translations", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "page_part_id"
  t.string   "locale"
  t.text     "body"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "page_part_translations", ["page_part_id"], :name => "index_page_part_translations_on_page_part_id"

create_table "page_parts", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "page_id"
  t.string   "title"
  t.text     "body"
  t.integer  "position"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "page_parts", ["id"], :name => "index_page_parts_on_id"
add_index "page_parts", ["page_id"], :name => "index_page_parts_on_page_id"

create_table "page_translations", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "page_id"
  t.string   "locale"
  t.string   "title"
  t.string   "custom_title"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "page_translations", ["page_id"], :name => "index_page_translations_on_page_id"

create_table "pages", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "parent_id"
  t.integer  "position"
  t.string   "path"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.boolean  "show_in_menu",        :default => true
  t.string   "link_url"
  t.string   "menu_match"
  t.boolean  "deletable",           :default => true
  t.string   "custom_title_type",   :default => "none"
  t.boolean  "draft",               :default => false
  t.boolean  "skip_to_first_child", :default => false
  t.integer  "lft"
  t.integer  "rgt"
  t.integer  "depth"
end

add_index "pages", ["depth"], :name => "index_pages_on_depth"
add_index "pages", ["id"], :name => "index_pages_on_id"
add_index "pages", ["lft"], :name => "index_pages_on_lft"
add_index "pages", ["parent_id"], :name => "index_pages_on_parent_id"
add_index "pages", ["rgt"], :name => "index_pages_on_rgt"
```

pages.rb: https://gist.github.com/grzegorzhauska/dcca44f3e2091c21400a
pages_for_inqueries.rb: https://gist.github.com/grzegorzhauska/997c355c2ce09d1da624

Comment: Post your schema.rb and seeds.rb (just the relevant portions containing the string 'meta_keywords." One of those files probably has a typographical error like 'page.meta_keywords'.

Comment: I don't think you quite understand what you're looking for... I asked for the relevant portions of those files based on the fact that the error tells you that some meta_keywords method is being called on a Page object. Page doesn't have a meta_keywords method -- it's likely being called as the result of a typographical error. Do a find in files for the string 'meta_keywords' (it may not be in those files because the error might be generated from a validation or filter or something else).

Comment: Yes you are right. I am just learning rails :). It very wierd but the error has just disapeared.

Comment: should I close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get this error is because meta_keywords used to exist, but now it doesn't.  Make sure you are using an up to date version of the `seo_meta` library.